# how to write.stream in append mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Getting error output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark.I wanted to get the out put on the console.

```
class StructSpark:
  def __init__(self, address, port):
    self.address = address
    self.port = port
    self.spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredWordcount").getOrCreate()
def getonline(self):
    lines = self.spark.readStream.format('socket').option('host', self.address).option('port', self.port).option(
        'includeTimestamp', 'true').load()
    words = lines.select(split(lines.value, ',').alias("value"), lines.timestamp)
    words1 = words.select((split(words.value[0], ',')).alias("key"),(split(words.value[0], ',')).alias("value"), lines.timestamp)
    windowedCount = words1.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes").groupBy(window(words1.timestamp, "5 minutes", "5 minutes"),words1.key).count()
    windowedCount.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")
    count = self.spark.sql("select * from updates where count > 1")
    with open('/home/vaibhav/Desktop/data.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(count))
    query = count.writeStream.outputMode("Append").format("console").start()
    query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and add some text on what is wrong with it and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are performing an aggregation operation in your dstream you can not perform write.stream in append mode.Either use it in 'Complete' mode or perform write.stream before an aggregation operation.